# How to import EXTERNAL resources for test cases in Katalon studio

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I wanted to create a data driven test cases where it has so many external resources such as word files/images/PDFs etc.

As the selenium scripts how I can add such kind of resources to my Katalon Script inside of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use files in your test cases with `Keywords`. Please consider following `Groovy` script. You need to specify

```
File directory = new File(directoryName)    
File[] fList = directory.listFiles()  
Arrays.sort(fList) 
for (File file : fList) {
  if ((file.isFile() && !(file.getName().contains('.txt')))) {
    WebUI.uploadFile(findTestObject('Object Repository/validateFile/input_signedFile'), (directory.toString() + '\\') + file.getName())
}
```